# Google auth for Restful api in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, node-modules, passport-google-oauth

Looking for a solution for hours but can't get a solution.
Can someone tell me that is there any way i can add google sign in for client side through my api?

My client side is Flutter for Android and iOS.

And will passport js work fine in api as it works in web user interface?

Comment: If you are just looking for a yes or no answer, then yes this should work.

Comment: Ty for answer. Can you please explain more?

Comment: A big issue with your question is that it's very unspecific. You should try to refine your question to specifically what you are hoping to answer. I can't figure out from your question what problem you are actually having.

Comment: See i already have register & login with email and password using jwt, but Just let me know with which method i can add google sign in.